# How can I prevent standard output from displaying as a standard error in csh or tcsh?

Tags: tcsh, csh

When executing a process in the background using '&', the standard output goes to standard error. This happens if an error is detected in the standard error output when executing a command, or if the parent shell is judged to be in error by the standard error output of the child shell, or if the parent shell judges an error due to the standard error output of the child shell, and then it will terminate abnormally. Is there a way to prevent this in csh or tcsh?

Comment: In an interactive shell initially stdin stdout and stderr are the same and equal the output of `tty`. So can you clarify why you expect stdout to differ from stderr at some point? Could you add in the question a short, reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Also, every shell I know "judges" a process to have errored by its _exit status_, not whether it output anything to standard error. This is true even if it's running as a background process. I agree with @a-b, you need to add an example that demonstrates what you're really asking about.